# Recode column of character variables in one data frame with numeric values in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, recode

I have the following dataframes:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'), y=c(.1,.2,.3))
xev_values <- data.frame(a=.01, b=.02, c=.03)
```

How do I recode the character variables in the `x` column of `df` with the numeric values in `xev_values` so that I have a new dataframe?

```
new_df <- data.frame(xev=c(.01,.02,.03), y=c(.1,.2,.3))
```

I see how to do this "manually" with recode:

```
new_df <- data.frame(xev=recode(df$x, 'a'=.01, 'b'=.02, 'c'=.03), y=df$y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert `xev_values` to long-format, conduct a join, and then select the columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  left_join(xev_values %>% gather(x, xev), by = "x") %>%
  select(xev, y)
df2
#    xev   y
# 1 0.01 0.1
# 2 0.02 0.2
# 3 0.03 0.3
```

Comment: Thanks. Ronak's answer works well, too, but this one fits nicely in my tidyverse workflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one row in `xev_values` we can compare `x` column in `df` with that of `names(xev_values)` and extract the corresponding column value.

```
df$x <- unlist(xev_values[1, match(df$x, names(xev_values))])

df 
#     x   y
#1 0.01 0.1
#2 0.02 0.2
#3 0.03 0.3
```